# Ideas for levitation using Earth's magnetic field and mu-metal

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, earth, geomagnetism, levitation

[image: BH curve(left), Hovering machine Design(right)]

I'm not sure the idea works or not. Please answer it and its reason.

1. As shown in Figure 1, when the ASTM A753 Alloy2 magnetic shielding alloy is exposed to an external magnetic field, the applied field value is about 30 A/m(similar to the mid-latitude region B field).As a result, a DC magnetic field of about 1.1 T is formed inside the shielding metal.
2. With this material, make a hollow cylindrical shielding bar as shown in Figure 2 and install batteries and wires in it, and the electric current to the direction of the red arrow will flow.
3. If the current flowing through the wire is set in the east-west direction as shown in the figure, a strong magnetic field is formed inside the shielding metal, but the magnetic field in the empty space inside the cylinder is significantly reduced due to the shielding effect.
4. The current flowing to the east and the geomagnetism in the north direction inside the shielding metal formed. As a result create an upward force, and the weak magnetic field inside the cylinder in which the current flows in the west creates a weak force to the downward. Finally the net force is formed upward and it's hovering.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the device you hope to build is not at all clear to me, however, any build-able magnetic device can be described as a dipole. Any magnetic dipole can only experience a net force from an external magnetic field if that field is non-uniform.  For any building sized volume, the magnetic field of the earth is weak and uniform. (And it is horizontal only near the equator.) It cannot be used as a source of levitation.

Comment: You don't seem to understand my idea. An east-directed current and a north-directed magnetic field create a upward magnetic force. In the case of weak geomagnetism, the magnetic field inside the metal is strengthened up to 1.1T using mu-metal to create a strong magnetic force. It is correct that the magnetic field is horizontal only near the equator, but if the mu-metal surface is horizontal, it can be adjusted to be sufficiently horizontal.